# Confusion about Dispatcher, TaskScheduler, SynchronizationContext in secondary GUI Thread

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, synchronizationcontext

As a result of another posting (see: [Using WPF Extended Toolkit MessageBox from other threads and curious behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298156/using-wpf-extended-toolkit-messagebox-from-other-threads-and-curious-behavior)), I am quite confused on the role and use of Dispatcher, TaskScheduler, SynchronizationContext in secondary GUIs (GUIs on their own threads) in WPF.  I can create another GUI Window on a different thread.  See my referenced stackoverflow post or http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/ for a discussion of how/why you might want to do this.  However, I am simply making use of the MainWindow dispatcher, SynchronizationContext and TaskScheduler.  Specifically, in my threadproc for the new GUI, I just have:

```
 public void AltWinThreadProc()
    {
        // Create our context, and install it:
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        _altWindow = new AltThreadWindow(_ui);  // _ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        //_altWindow = new AltThreadWindow();
        _altWindow.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

    }
```

When I tried to create a TaskScheduler within the new GUI on the second thread, things did not work.
Shouldn't it be possible for the GUI on the separate thread to have its own Dispatcher and TaskScheduler?

I have searched for this info, but to no avail.  I can't say I have a problem with how I'm doing it.  All is well.  But I'd like to understand what is going on.  Specifically:
1.  Is there really only 1 UI TaskScheduler? 
2.  Only 1 UI Dispatcher?
3.  Can someone explain (or provide a link) the connection between Dispatcher, TaskScheduler and SynchronizationContext ?

Thanks,

Dave